# Vision Framework - Text Recognition - Cannot recognize some umlaut diacritics

Tags: ios, text-recognition

I am using Vision Framework to recognize text in my app. However, some umlaut diacritics are recognized incorrectly, for example: Grudziński (The incorrect result is: Grudzinski).

I already changed language to DE (because my app needs to support DE text) and tried to use [VNRecognizeTextRequest#customWord](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrecognizetextrequest/3152640-customwords) with [usesLanguageCorrection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrecognizetextrequest/3166773-useslanguagecorrection) but the result still is incorrect.

Does Apple provide any APIs to solve this problem? This issue also happens when I open the Gallery on my phone, copy text from images, and paste it to another place.